# Change tempo of audio file without changing the pitch of the clip

Tags: audio, audiocontext, audiobuffer, web-audio-api

I created a audiocontext instance suing web audio , and loaded the music file as a audiobuffer into it and i can play the songs now , and my question is:Is there any way i can set tempo of the audiosource(audiobuffer) by any node and play accordingly ?

I have tried with

```
var context = AudioContext();
source= context.createBufferSource();
context.nodes.push(source);
source.buffer = Audiobuffer;
source.playbackRate.value = 1.5;
```

And the problem above is , it is changing the pitch of the audio files, how to change the tempo without changing the pitch ?.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/playbackRate will act as forward and rewind it will always act like that , perhaps you can try with the sound touch library  https://github.com/also/soundtouch-js

Comment: cannot explain everything in a comment , so please try that library , that will  be usefull for what you are seeking.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm looking for this, too.

Comment: No @Paulie, if you found please post that here